# Como leio uma arquivo do assets como string

Tags: android

Como eu faço para ler como string um arquivo de texto do Android que esta dentro da pasta Assets?

Answer (score 1):

`getAssets().open()` ira retornar um `InputStream`.

Leia ela usando a API de entrada e saída(I/O) padrão do Java.
Como no exemplo a seguir:

```
StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
InputStream json=getAssets().open("book/contents.json");
BufferedReader in=
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"));
String str;

while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
  buf.append(str);
}

in.close();
```